# Function that will return the updated table in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-update

I have these two subqueries which work perfectly fine.
I want these two subqueries in one function and give the result together.
The function will return the UPDATED table.

This query updates the **product_Details** TABLE1 where **start_Date** matches with the **current_Date** and **time**. This will ADD **offer/promotional** price by matching the **id** with the other TABLE2 named **pricing**. HERE, price_and_price_Type is **JSONB** TYPE object.

```
update product_Details
            SET price_and_price_Type = price_and_price_Type || 
                ( pps.details::jsonb ) 
                FROM ( 
                select id, price_Details as details 
                from pricing 
                where to_char(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') = to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                group by id, details
                ) as pps 
                where product_Details.id = "pps".id;
```

The following query updates the **product_Details** TABLE1 where end_date  matches with the **current_Date** and **time**. This will REMOVE **offer/promotional** price IF ALREADY EXISTS by matching the **id** with the other TABLE2 named **pricing**. HERE, price_and_price_Type is **JSONB** TYPE object.

```
update product_Details
set price_And_price_Type= price_And_price_Type - pps.price_details
            FROM ( 
                select id, jsonb_object_keys(price_Details) price_details 
                from pricing 
                where to_char(end_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') = to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                group by id, price_details
                ) as pps 
            where product_Details.id = "pps".id;
```

I tried to write this function which isnt working as I want to return product_Details table with the updated value. But, I'm getting errors as it wants column name which I cant provide as update isnt inserting new data, Its just an update!

The function is written as.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PRODUCT()
RETURNS TABLE() 
AS 
$$
BEGIN
return query 
update product_Details
            SET price_and_price_Type = price_and_price_Type || 
                ( pps.details::jsonb ) 
                FROM ( 
                select id, price_Details as details 
                from pricing 
                where to_char(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') = to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                group by id, details
                ) as pps 
                where product_Details.id = "pps".id; 
update product_Details
set price_And_price_Type= price_And_price_Type - pps.price_details
            FROM ( 
                select id, jsonb_object_keys(price_Details) price_details 
                from pricing 
                where to_char(end_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') = to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                group by id, price_details
                ) as pps 
            where product_Details.id = "pps".id;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

How to write this function to fit these two subqueries in the function and where I can just call the function and get the updated table.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps `UPDATE ... RETURNING *`. Try doing it with a single update.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, what would be the  () in RETURN TABLE ( )?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe If I try this- CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PRODUCT()               RETURNS TABLE(id_num int, updated_price_And_price_Details jsonb) , The error pops, UPDATE query does not return tuples

Comment: Then make it return tuples.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm new to postgresql so unable to sort this out. Could you please help with the function?

Comment: I thought I did - I recommended `UPDATE ... RETURNING`. PostgreSQL is complaining that the `UPDATE` does not return any data.

Answer (score 0):

As proposed by @Laurenz, adding a `RETURNING` clause would make the job if you had only one UPDATE in your function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PRODUCT()
RETURNS setof record LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS 
$$
BEGIN
return query 
update product_Details
            SET price_and_price_Type = price_and_price_Type || 
                ( pps.details::jsonb ) 
                FROM ( 
                select id, price_Details as details 
                from pricing 
                where to_char(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') = to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                group by id, details
                ) as pps 
                where product_Details.id = "pps".id
RETURNING * ;
END;
$$;
```

But as you have two UPDATE in the same function, if you want to get the results from both, then you need to group them in a SELECT clause :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PRODUCT()
RETURNS setof record LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS 
$$
BEGIN
return query 
WITH update1 AS (
update product_Details
            SET price_and_price_Type = price_and_price_Type || 
                ( pps.details::jsonb ) 
                FROM ( 
                select id, price_Details as details 
                from pricing 
                where to_char(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') = to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                group by id, details
                ) as pps 
                where product_Details.id = "pps".id
                returning *
), update2 AS (
update product_Details
            SET price_And_price_Type= price_And_price_Type - pps.price_details
            FROM ( 
                select id, jsonb_object_keys(price_Details) price_details 
                from pricing 
                where to_char(end_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') = to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                group by id, price_details
                ) as pps 
                where product_Details.id = "pps".id
                returning *
) SELECT * FROM update1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM update2 ;
END;
$$ ;
```

The same function in sql language :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PRODUCT()
RETURNS setof record LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE AS $$
WITH update1 AS (
update product_Details
            SET price_and_price_Type = price_and_price_Type || 
                ( pps.details::jsonb ) 
                FROM ( 
                select id, price_Details as details 
                from pricing 
                where to_char(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') = to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                group by id, details
                ) as pps 
                where product_Details.id = "pps".id
                returning price_And_price_Type
), update2 AS (
update product_Details
            SET price_And_price_Type= price_And_price_Type - pps.price_details
            FROM ( 
                select id, jsonb_object_keys(price_Details) price_details 
                from pricing 
                where to_char(end_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') = to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                group by id, price_details
                ) as pps 
                where product_Details.id = "pps".id
                returning price_And_price_Type
) SELECT * FROM update1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM update2 ;
$$ ;
```

Comment: I am getting the error while running this code- "materialize mode required, but it is not allowed in this context." @Edouard

Comment: never heard about this error before ... Do you have the error code ?

Comment: ERROR:  materialize mode required, but it is not allowed in this context
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function product() line 3 at RETURN QUERY
SQL state: 0A000  @Edouard

Comment: can you test with the sql function I have added in my answer and see if you get the same error ? What is your postgresql version ? Do you confirm `product_Details` is a table ?

Comment: SQL function works completely fine, but if I use the code that goes with plpgsql language, the problem arises. 'RETURN QUERY' is raising the concern. What could be done to fix this? @Edouard

Comment: does it change anything if you replace `RETURNING *` by `RETURNING price_And_price_Type` in your plpgsql function ?